# What is the best coding style for performance?

Tags: programming, coding-style, meta-programming

**The problem of Mathematica** is there are **too many ways** to perform one task. That leads to confusion for new users because the performances of these methods are so different.

I'm learning the **best coding style** to gain performance in Mathematica. However, there is something that I don't understand and need the explication of the experts.

---

Let takes this simple example. I have a list of data consist of 10^7 elements {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}. Now I want to make a list like {{x1,f[y1]},{x2,f[y2]},...}. For this task, there are **about 13 methods**.

```
list = Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 1., 10^7}];
```

This is the packed array:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list]
On["Packing"];
```

And here is the performance of **these 13 methods.** The **performance difference between these methods is huge.** (from 0.5s to 20s). The time is measured by `AbsoluteTiming`, the `f` function is `Sin`.

[image]

---

**Here are my questions:**

- Q1: Let's compare methods #11 vs #10. Why using only one built-in function MapAt is much slower than {Copy the whole list, apply function f to the Part, and recall the new list}? In general, using 1 Function is faster than combine several functions.
- Q2: Between the #9, and #10. Again, using MapAt, Pure function, and Map is faster than using MapAt with a built-in position option. Why? What is the purpose of implementing the position option in MapAt when this method is slower than combining other existing functions?
- Q3: Compare #3, and #4, using the same function Table, but with a different approach, the performance is 3 times slowers. Should Mathematica eliminate the method that is not optimized?
- Q4: Compare 6 and 4. Method 6 is the **Functional Style** with Apply, Pure Function. Method 4 is a **Procedural way** and breaking the list into each element. Why the functional style which treats the data as the whole list is much slower than the naive Procedural style?
- A1: Unpacking verify is very useful.

So in general, which is your preferred coding style for performance? I would like to learn.

---

```
In[138]:= $Version

Out[138]= "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"
```

---

**Here is the code to verify:**

```
list = Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 1., 10^7}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list]
On["Packing"];


timelist = {
   Transpose[{#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]}] &@Transpose@list; // 
    AbsoluteTiming,
   Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], Sin[list[[All, 2]]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming,
   Table[{i[[1]], Sin[i[[2]]]}, {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming,
   Table[{list[[i, 1]], Sin[list[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]; // 
    AbsoluteTiming,
   {#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]} & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming,
   {#1, Sin[#2]} & @@@ list; // AbsoluteTiming,
   MapThread[{#1, Sin[#2]} &, Transpose[list]]; // AbsoluteTiming,
   Inner[#1[#2] &, {# &, Sin[#] &}, Transpose[list], List]; // 
    AbsoluteTiming,
   MapAt[Sin, #, 2] & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming,
   MapAt[Sin, list, {All, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming,
   AbsoluteTiming[list2 = list; 
    list2[[All, 2]] = Sin[list2[[All, 2]]]; list2;],
   Map[Composition[
       Through, {Composition[Identity, First], 
        Composition[Sin, Last]}], list]; // AbsoluteTiming,
   list /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Sin[y]}; // AbsoluteTiming
   };

funclist = ToString /@ {
    HoldForm[Transpose[{#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]}] &@Transpose@list],
    HoldForm[Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], Sin[list[[All, 2]]]}]],
    HoldForm[Table[{i[[1]], Sin[i[[2]]]}, {i, list}]],
    HoldForm[
     Table[{list[[i, 1]], Sin[list[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]],
    HoldForm[{#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]} & /@ list],
    HoldForm[{#1, Sin[#2]} & @@@ list],
    HoldForm[MapThread[{#1, Sin[#2]} &, Transpose[list]]],
    HoldForm[Inner[#1[#2] &, {# &, Sin[#] &}, Transpose[list], List];],
    HoldForm[MapAt[Sin, #, 2] & /@ list],
    HoldForm[MapAt[Sin, list, {All, 2}]],
    HoldForm[list2 = list; list2[[All, 2]] = Sin[list2[[All, 2]]]; 
     list2],
    HoldForm@
     Map[Composition[
       Through, {Composition[Identity, First], 
        Composition[Sin, Last]}], list],
    HoldForm[list /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Sin[y]}]
    };

unpack = {"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"};;
sol = SortBy[
   Transpose[{Range@Length@funclist, funclist, unpack, 
     timelist[[All, 1]]}], Last];
Grid[PrependTo[sol, {"#", "Method", "Unpacking", "AbsoluteTiming"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @chris

Comment: oh, thank you. I edited it. Cheers

Comment: In general, you want to do operations on whole arrays as much as possible. Adding arrays; dotting them; using `Listable` functions (like `Sin`) on the array directly. That sort of thing. That way you ensure the least amount of high-level overhead.

Comment: I think most of your questions can be answered by considering array unpacking: See e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) and related. You can use `On["Packing"]` and run the examples from your question to see which examples unpack how much

Comment: Also, please include the code for your tests in the question, so others can play around with it without having to enter everything manually

Comment: BTW, `Transpose[{#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]}] &@Transpose@list` is probably faster than any of your alternatives.

Comment: And don't forget `Parallelize` for very large computations of this form, which took 3.1 seconds here.

Comment: The question is updated with your suggestion. Further discussion is required.